# Open a fullsize window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I hv a requirement, when I'll click a link, a new fullsize window will open. When I am going for 1st option, it is working fine in Firefox(ESR 26.2.0)

But, 2nd option isnt working at all. Fullsize window isn't hetting opened.

```
1st option:
    window.open(windowUrl, "popWindow", "height=1000, width=1500, scrollbars=1, resizeable=1");
2nd option:    
    window.open(windowUrl, "popWindow", "fullscreen=1, scrollbars=1, resizeable=1");
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

> **fullscreen**
>
> Do not use. Not implemented in Mozilla. There are no plans to implement this feature in Mozilla.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: fullscreen not implemented.]